# ReArrange a number with ascending digits

Tags: c

I have to solve a problem where one of the important tasks is to reorder the digits of the input in ascending order and we are not allowed to use arrays and lists. I have no problem with that and my code works, but only if we do not consider leading 0, which we should in this problem. The only way I see how to do is to check digit by digit and then add then ordered by multiplying the number by 10 and adding the next digit. (1*10 = 10, 10+3= 13, we got 1 and 3 ordered) However, if we have a 0 in our number this method will not work because if I want to make 0123 with the * 10 method, I won't be able to have the  0 as the first digit never. Does anyone know how to solve this? My code is below:

```
int ascendingNumbers (int n) {   //This function sorts the number on an ascending order
    int number = n;
    int sortedN = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        int toSortNumber = number;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++) {
            int digit = toSortNumber % 10;
            if (digit == i) {
                if (digit == 0) {
                    sortedN==10;
                }
                sortedN *= 10;
                sortedN += digit;
            }
            toSortNumber /= 10;
        }
    }
    return sortedN;
}
```

Comment: I do not see how you can consider leading zero when you are working with numeric types (`int`). Leading zero would only exist if you are representing the number as a string, which is an array which you are not allowed to use.

Comment: With the constraints you've mentioned, returning an `int`, it is IMPOSSIBLE to have leading zeros.  Are you absolutely sure that is part of the given problem?

Comment: `sortedN==10;`? Don't you mean `sortedN=10;`?

Comment: If you want leading digits, either count the digits and return the count so that you can use field-width and `0` prefix when printing with `printf`; Or read the number as a string.

Comment: This is probably not a helpful comment, but: If someone told me to arrange something in order, without using arrays or lists, I would ask them what they were smoking, and tell them to take a hike.  Seriously.  There is no point to this exercise.  It will teach you nothing you'll ever use.  Take a 0 on this assignment, and go look at flowers and trees or something, instead.  Your soul will thank you.

Comment: @SteveSummit 's comment is spot on.  If you want to learn something, use sprintf to write the integer into an array and sort it with qsort.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think ill take your advice, my soul really needs it ahah

Answer (score 2):

Normally I don't do homework problems, but for especially awful ones I'll make an exception.
(Also I'm making an exception to my general rule not to have anything to do with these absurd "desert island" constraints, where you're stranded after a shipwreck and your C compiler's array functionality got damaged in the storm, or something.)

I assume you're allowed to call functions.  In that case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count the number of digits 'd' in 'n'. */
int countdigits(int n, int d)
{
    int ret = 0;
    /* do/while so consider "0" as "0", not nothing */
    do {
        if(n % 10 == d) ret++;
        n /= 10;
    } while(n > 0);
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;
    printf("enter your number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("digits: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int n2 = countdigits(n, i);
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < n2; j++) putchar('0' + i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This solution does *not* involve a function `int ascendingNumbers()` as you asked about.  If you want to handle leading zeroes, as explained in the comments, you can't do it with a function that returns an `int`.

Comment: One up for the opening …

Comment: If I were a professor, my biggest fear would be Steve Summit commenting on one of my homework with the line "Normally I don't do homework but, oh boy, I'll make an exception...". Btw I think that OP's assignment has been poorly explained (to OP), maybe there's some missing piece of info that would make it a normal assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your zero problem is solved, check it...

```
class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 24035217;
        int n = number, count = 0;
        int sortedN = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            n = n / 10;
            ++count;
        }
        for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
            int toSortNumber = number;
            for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
                int digit = toSortNumber % 10;
               // printf("\nBefore i = %d, x = %d, toSortNumber = %d, sortedN = %d, digit = %d",i,x,toSortNumber,sortedN,digit);
                if (digit == i) {
                    sortedN *= 10;
                    sortedN += digit;
    
                }
              //  printf("\nAfter i = %d, x = %d, toSortNumber = %d, sortedN = %d, digit = %d",i,x,toSortNumber,sortedN,digit);
                toSortNumber /= 10;
            }
        }
    
        System.out.print(sortedN);
        }
    }
```